# Emma doesn't embed source code to html report

Tags: java, ant, code-coverage, report, emma

I have a problem with Ant and Emma a code coverage plugin, it makes report, but without source code.

I got following code in my build.xml

init emma

```
    <taskdef resource="emma_ant.properties" />   
    <path id="run.classpath">  
       <pathelement location="${instr}" />  
       <path  refid="build.classpath"/>  
       <pathelement path="${ant.home}/lib/junit-4.5.jar"/>  
       <pathelement path="${ant.home}/lib/emma.jar"/>  
    </path>
```

making instr

```
    <target name="instr" depends="compile">  
        <emma>  
          <instr instrpathref="build.classpath"  
                 destdir="${instr}"
                 metadatafile="${coverage}/metadata.emma"  
                 merge="true"  
          />  
        </emma>  
    </target>
```

setting properties

```
    <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.file=${coverage}/coverage.emma" />  
    <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.merge=true" />
```

making report

```
    <emma>  
        <report sourcepath="${src}" >  
            <fileset dir="${coverage}" >  
                <include name="*.emma" />  
            </fileset>  

            <html outfile="${coverage}/coverage.html"/>             
        </report>      
    </emma>
```

This works nice. It outputs to console:

```
 [report] processing input files ...
 [report] 2 file(s) read and merged in 10 ms
 [report] not all instrumented classes were compiled with source file
 [report] debug data: no sources will be embedded in the report.
 [report] line coverage requested in a report of type [html] but
 [report] not all instrumented classes were compiled with line number
 [report] debug data: this column will be removed from the report.
 [report] showing up to 3 classes without full debug info per package:
 [report]   ...
 [report] writing [html] report to [C:\...] ...
```

I want see my source code in report, how can I fix it? I studied documentation of emma and unfortunately there isn't anything related to this problem.

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I solved a problem.

I added `debug="true"` to javac and it works now.

Comment: +1 for solving your own problem. I was just about to suggest that.